# Passing dynamic value to path name in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, path, filesystems, mapping

I am new to C# and reactjs and am stuck in this conundrum. I am using a function to download the images from url into my local file. Doing that I am specifying the file path.

The function is this:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("GetImages")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetImages()
        {
            Somewhere();
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {

                var url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tsl-coil-qlty- 
                           monitoring-dev.appspot.com/o/1a60ce3b-eddf-4e72-b2af-b6e99873e926? 
                           alt=media&token=61399a02-1009-4bb9-ad89-d1235df900e4";
                webClient.DownloadFile(url, @"D:\CQMS_Images_JPEG\image4.jpg");
            }
        
            return Ok();

        }
```

what I will try to do now is pass the url dynamically. That will be taken care of and is the easy part. But what I want to do is also pass the filepath dynamically.

Like on the coming of the first image I want to pass the path as

first image:D:\CQMS_Images_JPEG\image1.jpg

second image:D:\CQMS_Images_JPEG\image2.jpg

Third image:D:\CQMS_Images_JPEG\image3.jpg

..... and so on

I want this part to be dynamic:
D:\CQMS_Images_JPEG\image{**image number dynamic**}.jpg

How do I do this . Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to get file name from url:

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(url);
webClient.DownloadFile(url, $@"D:\CQMS_Images_JPEG\{fileName}");
```

but if you want to set filename like image1, image2,...

```
int fileNumber = 0;

public IHttpActionResult GetImages()
{
  Somewhere();
  using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
  {
    var url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tsl-coil-qlty-monitoring-dev.appspot.com/o/1a60ce3b-eddf-4e72-b2af-b6e99873e926?alt=media&token=61399a02-1009-4bb9-ad89-d1235df900e4";
    webClient.DownloadFile(url, $@"D:\CQMS_Images_JPEG\image{fileNumber}.jpg");
  }
   fileNumber +=1;
   return Ok();

 }
```

Comment: can you explain what this does= var fileName = Path.GetFileName(url); will I not have to set the file path if I do this?

Comment: if your url is http://www.google.com/myimage.jpg then Path.GetFileName(url) result will be myimage.jpg,  It depends on what you do